# Django - why is edit form posting to edit url + create url on top of each other?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm reusing my 'create' form for an edit view. 'Create' routing works just fine, but when the 'edit' form is submitted, my terminal says it tries to `POST /comment/edit/26/comment/add/`.

I was trying a custom class view, so then switched to just generic UpdateView:

```
class CommentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['title']
```

and still the same thing. So I figure maybe it's a problem with the ModelForm or with urls?

Here's forms.py

```
from django import forms
from comments.models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
```

etc. -- the form itself looks like this:

```
<form id="new-form" role="form" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <p>{{ form.title }}</p>
      <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <a href="/">Cancel</a>
      </p>
 </form>
```

aaand urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from ratings.views import (home, CommentCreate, CommentUpdate)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='comment-home'),
    url(r'comment/add/$', CommentCreate.as_view(), name='comment-add'),
    url(r'comment/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='comment-edit')
]
```

So I've read that a form has its action set automatically to the view that rendered it. Looks like it gets that (`/comment/edit/26/`) but then every time chucks `comment/add/` on the end too. Don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor your URL patterns at the start.

```
url(r'^comment/add/$', CommentCreate.as_view(), name='comment-add'),
url(r'^comment/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='comment-edit')
```

Comment: That was totally it. Also found out I had a stray js handler on the form id that was AJAXing it. That was bad - but yes, definitely needed to anchor the regex for urls.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your `CommentCreate` and `CommentUpdate` views:

```py
    form_class = CommentForm
```

The missing `action` attribute on the `<form>` could be interfering as well. It may help to add `action=""`.